# Check Prefix in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

**I got correct output but beyond Time Limit.**

**Question :** A list Li containing (not necessarily distinct) N words and Q queries. Each query consists of a string x. For each query, find how many strings in the List Li has the string x as its prefix.\

```
class Solution{
    static List<Integer> prefixCount(int N, int Q, String li[], String query[])
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int l,c;
        for(int i=0; i<Q; i++){
            c = 0;
             
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
                if(li[j].length()>=query[i].length()){
                if(li[j].substring(0,query[i].length()).equals(query[i])){
                    c++;
                }
                }
            }
            list.add(c);
        }
    return list;
    }
}
```

**How can I optimize the above code?**

Comment: you need to use Trie and maintain a count at each node for how many times you traversed through the node while creating the Trie.
After this traverse through Trie for the prefix and the count at the node is your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Trie with the given strings maintaining a count at each node on how many time the node was travesed while creating a trie.

Now for each prefix String you traverse through the array, if you successfully traverse until your Prefix string length in the Trie, answer for that prefix string is count at the node, else answer is 0.